# check if all values in a column of one table exists in another table

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I wanted to know the command to check if all the values in one table(created using select statement) is present in the other table (created using select command) all in one select statement.for eg ,i have a attribute `fid` and `faculty_name` in **faculty table** and `fid` ,`class_name`, `room_n`o in another. ***how do i check all faculty who teaches in all the room present?***

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: **that is really hard to read what you have i mean you have everything bolded in a code block.you should format your question better.**

Answer (score 8):

Poorly asked question, but

```
--
-- all faculty without a class
--
select *
from faculty f
where not exists ( select *
                   from class c
                   where c.fid = f.fid
                 )
--
-- all classes wihout faculty
--
select *
from class c
where not exists ( select *
                   from faculty f
                   where f.fid = c.fid
                 )
--
-- all-in-one. Each returned row represents
-- either a faculty or class without a match
-- in the other
--
select *
from      faculty f
full join class   c on c.fid = f.fid
where c.fid is null
   or f.fid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
select a.faculty_name, b.class_name, b.room_no 
  from faculty a, Table2 b 
 where a.fid = b.fid
```

Answer (score -1):

Let’s say you have two tables: faculty and class. Fid (faculty id) should be the primary key on faculty table, and foreign key on class table.

Here only can be two cases you are looking for: all faculties have class or only some faculties.

To find who has class:

```
SELECT
  fid,
  faculty_name
FROM
  faculty f
  INNER JOIN
  class c
  ON
      f.fid = c.fid
```

To find who don’t have class:

```
SELECT
  fid,
  faculty_name
FROM
   faculty f
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
   class c
   ON
      f.fid = c.fid
WHERE
  c.fid is null
```